# How to validate only few controls ? Anyway to group it on click of a button?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a table design, used by recruiter to upload profiles. Each row contains a txtname,txtContactNo,txtEmailID and a submit link button at the end of each row(contained in last column of the table). There are 5 such rows. I want all the txt boxes in row 1 to be filled before clicking on btnSubmit1 (and same with all other row on click of their corresponding submit button). I have placed requiredFieldValidator to all the controls of all the rows. If i click on submit button of first row, it giving error on all the controls of all the rows. I want that my first submit button should check only those controls that are in first row, instead of all the controls.

Please Help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Textcontrols and the Button causing the Submit have a Property called `ValidationGroup`.
So set the same ValidationGroup for the Textboxes in the first row and button 1

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ValidationGroup` property on the validators and submit button, by row.

E.g. all the validators and btnSubmit in row 1, `ValidationGroup="valgroup1"`, 
all the validators and btnSubmit in row 2, `ValidationGroup="valgroup2"`, etc.